# Full Text Search through specific column using django postgres's builtin full text search

Tags: django, postgresql, search, full-text-search

I'd like to use full text search on my database and choose which columns to search through. Is there a way to search through a specific column (like only fruits) when I only I have one search_vector field in my Food model that contains all the columns (fruits, vegetables, dairy). I'd also like to search through all the columns so that's why I combined all the search vectors.

I am using Django 1.11

Here's my model:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    fruits = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    vegetables = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dairy = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True)
```

Here's how I store the vectors:

```
vector= SearchVector('fruits', weight='A') + \
        SearchVector('vegetables', weight='B') + \
        SearchVector('dairy', weight='C') + \
Food.objects.annotate(document=vector).values_list('document', flat=True)


for f in Food.objects.annotate(document=vector):
    f.search_vector = f.document
    f.save(update_fields=['search_vector'])
```

Here's how I search:

```
search_result = Food.objects\
    .annotate(rank=SearchRank(F('search_vector'), "apple"))\
    .filter(search_vector="apple")\
```

Is there an easy way of only searching in fruit column in the search_vector that I set up, or would I have to set up a separate search vector for each column?

Answer (score 3):

Was able to accomplish this by simply filtering

```
result = Food.objects.filter(**{fruits + "__search": "apple"})
```